# Bad view of animations with navigation from page to page (use MvvmCross)

Tags: ios, navigation, transition, mvvmcross, xamarin.mac

I am developing ios application by xamarin. For navigation in my app I use MvvmCross nuget and ShowViewModel method in my viewmodel.
I have listview, that navigate for children page after click at item. But at time navigation from page to page - second page is overlapping first and in result I have next situation:

[image]

I attached links to archive with solution of project with a great hope that you will help me solve my problem:
http://1drv.ms/1M0jBZ8

Help me!

Comment: That's because you set these 2 values:

            this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            this.TableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

if you set some color to this.View.BackgroundColor you won't have that problem... but yes, you will lose your effect of transparency.